# How to Access DataTemplate inside a ResourceDictionary in code behind in WinRT?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, datatemplate, controltemplate, winrt-component

I have defined a DataTemplate inside a ResourceDictionary. I need to access the DataTemplate in the code behind. (i.e) I **need to set this DataTemplate defined inside a ResourceDictionary to a ContentControl.ContentTemplate property in the code behind**. How can i achieve this. 
Below is the my xaml code.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="template">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" 
                BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=value}" Padding="2" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the code that I tried:

```
ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///sample.xaml", UriKind.Absolute) };
object tem;
rd.TryGetValue("template", out tem);
```

Can anyone point me how to access it?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've tried? You should cast `tem` into `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I just made a sample project to try out your approach and it works perfectly. You need to cast `tem` as Chris already pointed out, but that's it. What errors do you get? Maybe your `Uri` for the `ResourceDictionary` is wrong.